# How to display DataGridView outside the parent control like GroupBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

[image: Get The Attached Snapshot]

How can I display `DataGridView` outside the parent control (eg. `GroupBox`) like `DropDownList`.

I want to display `DataGridView` with full of size and its content whenever I double click the Textbox but `DataGridView` is partially showing and hides outside the GroupBox (its parent control).

Please refer to the attached snapshot.

```
ClearText = New DefaultClass
ClearText.ClearTextBox(Me)

Try
    con = New SqlConnection(ConnStrSql)
    con.Open()
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [CODE] as [Member CODE],[NAME] as [Name],[FNAME]as [Father's Name] FROM [MsumCOOP].[dbo].[MEMBER] ORDER BY [CODE] asc,[NAME] asc,[FNAME] asc", con)
    dt = New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgvMemberCode.DataSource = dt
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        dgvMemberCode.Location = New Point(txtMemberCode.Left, txtMemberCode.Bottom)
        dgvMemberCode.Visible = True
    Else : dgvMemberCode.Visible = False
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("No DATA Fetched" + ex.Message)
Finally
    con.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: Did you upload the same picture twice?

Comment: Anyway, if your layout is fixed, you can take the DataGridView out of its parent (and use Top/Left properties). Can you post your code?

Comment: I have shared codes. Please suggest me some solutions.

Comment: You would have to parent the grid on a different form and then show that form at the desired position.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, both mentioned in commens.

1) Simple, but limited

If your grid is allways small enought to fit on form boundaries, put it into your Form.Controls instead of GroupBox.Controls. As suggested by @Farhan Ahmed Saifi

2) Full, but complicated

Create second form with the grid, tune BorderStyle and so on and show it on required coordinates. This will require more handling with Show/Hide/LostFocus/PositionChanged logic. As suggested by @jmcilhinney